# How to split files using Perl?

Tags: text-processing, perl

Each div should be separated as individual files.

#### Input.txt

```
[[div]]
line 1
line 2
...
[[/div]]

[[div]]
line 3
line 4
line 5
...
[[/div]]

[[div]]
line 6
line 7
...
[[/div]]
```

#### filename.txt

```
fm.html
chap01.html
bm.html
```

#### Output needed

#### fm.html

```
<html>
<body>
line 1
line 2
...
</body>
</html>
```

#### chap01.html

```
<html>
<body>
line 3
line 4
line 5
...
</body>
</html>
```

#### bm.html

```
<html>
<body>
line 6
line 7
...
</body>
</html>
```

Coding that i have tried now.. but it returns last div in all files... And need to add meta...Kindly need solution

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(REDA,"filename.txt");
@namef=<REDA>;
open(RED,"input.txt");
open(WRITX,">input1.txt");
while(<RED>)
   {
    chomp($_);
    $_="$_"."<cr>";
    print WRITX $_;
   }
close(RED);
close(WRITX);
open(REDQ,"input1.txt");
open(WRITQ,">input2.txt");
while(<REDQ>)
   {
                $_=~s/\[\[div\]\]<cr>/\n\[\[div\]\]/gi;
    print WRITQ $_;
   }
close(REDQ);
close(WRITQ);
open(REDE,"input2.txt");
while(<REDE>)
   {
   foreach $namef (@namef)
    {
         chomp($namef);
         $namef=~s/\.[a-z]+//gi;
        open(WRIT1,">$namef.html");
            if(/\[\[div\]\]/i)
            {
                chomp($_);
                $_=~s/<cr>/\n/gi;
                print WRIT1 $_;
            }
         }
    }
close(REDA);
close(REDE);
close(REDX);
close(WRIT1);
system ("del input1.txt");
system ("del input2.txt");
```

Comment: As am very new to perl... kindly help me to start

Comment: Seems like some simple searching for doing loops in perl would get you at least started. Please try and do some of this your self, and others here can then offer assistance. http://perl.about.com/od/perltutorials/a/forloop_2.htm

Comment: Are the `div`s always separated by a blank line?

Comment: Yes we can use that as pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure the `[[div]]` sections are separated by blank lines, you can make use of Perl's paragraph mode slurp which divides a file into chunks separated by one or more blank lines. The following code (tested) does what you need. Execute the following in a terminal where the current directory contains the relevant files:

```
perl -n00 -e '
    BEGIN{ #Executed before input.txt is read
        open $f,"<","filename.txt";
        @names = split /\n+/,<$f> #Split is needed because we changed the input record separator
    }

    # The following is executed for each "paragraph" (div section)
    s!\[\[div\]\]\n!<html>\n<body>\n!; # substitute <html>\n<body\n instead of [[div]]
    s!\[\[/div\]\]\n!</body>\n</html>!; # substitute </body>\n</html> instead of [[/div]]
    $content{shift @names}=$_; #Add the modified content to hash keyed by file name

    END{ #This is executed after the whole of input.txt has been read
        for(keys %content){ #For each file we want to create
            open $of,">",$_;
            print $of $content{$_}
        }
    }
' input.txt
```

**Update**

If you want to use the above code as a Perl script, you can do the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $f,'<','filename.txt' or die "Failed to open filename.txt: $!\n";
my @names;
chomp(@names=<$f>);

open my $if,'<','input.txt' or die "Failed to open input.txt: $!\n";
my %content;
while(my $paragraph=do{local $/="";<$if>}){
    $paragraph=~ s!\[\[div\]\]\n!<html>\n<body>\n!;
    $paragraph=~ s!\[\[/div\]\]\n!</body>\n</html>!;
    $content{shift @names}=$paragraph;
}

for(keys %content){
    open my $of,'>',$_ or die "Failed to open $_ : $!\n";
    print $of $content{$_}
}
```

Save the above as (say) `split_file.pl`, make it executable via `chmod +x split_file.pl` then run it as `./split_file.pl`.

Comment: Sorry i have some compliation errors as follows: 

Bareword found where operator expected at 1.pl line 18, near "' input"
(Might be a runaway multi-line '' string starting on line 1)
(Missing operator before input?)
syntax error at 1.pl line 1, near "n00 -e "
Execution of 1.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Can you clarify how to solve this?

Comment: @PLT Try it without the comments. It seems that if you copy-paste it, a newline gets inserted somehow in the middle of a comment. I don't really understand why it's happening: I just copy pasted the whole thing into my terminal and it ran well. Note that I also updated the code to remove an extra newline after the final `</html>`.

Comment: @PLT You _are_ pasting this code into a terminal, right? Because this is not meant to be put into a file and run as a script.

Comment: Can i know how to code this in a perl file with extension .pl

Comment: @PLT Coding this in a file would require several more lines to open the `input.txt` file and read from it paragraph by paragraph. You can save this code as a `bash` script though.

Comment: I didnt know about bash completely... Can you help me how to run that... Also i have tried a perl code. it returns only the last div  in all files splited.

Comment: Ya great... I have got it... This coding is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @file_names;
## Read the list of file names
open(my $fh,"$ARGV[0]");
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp; #remove new line character from the end of the line
    push @file_names,$_;
}

my $counter=0;
my ($file_name,$fn);
## Read the input file
open($fh,"$ARGV[1]");
while (<$fh>) {
    ## If this is an opening DIV, open the next output file,
    ## and set $counter to 1.
    if (/\[\[div\]\]/) {
    $counter=1;
    $file_name=shift(@file_names);
    open($fn, '>',"$file_name");
    }
    ## If this is a closing DIV, print the line and set $counter back to 0
    if (/\[\[\/div\]\]/) {
    $counter=0;
    print $fn $_;
    close($fn);
    }
    ## Print into the corresponding file handle if $counter is 1
    print $fn $_ if $counter==1
}
```

Save the script as `foo.pl` and run it like this:

```
perl foo.pl filename.txt Input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In Perl you can loop through the contents of file `filename.txt` like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# somescript.pl

open (my $fh, "<", "filename.txt");
my @files = <$fh>;
close ($fh);

foreach my $file (@files) {
    print "$file";
}
```

Put the above in a file called `somescript.pl`, make it executable, `chmod +x somescript.pl`, and run it:

```
$ ./somescript.pl 
fm.html
chap01.html
bm.html
```

You can see that it's now reading in the file `filename.txt` and printing each line out to the screen. I leave the rest to you to try. If you get stuck ask for help.

I  would use the same approach that I did to read in the `filename.txt` file for reading in the `input.txt` file.

Answer (score 0):

Writing it in rather more idiomatic Perl, you might get something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# First argument is the name of the file that contains
# the filenames.
open my $fn, shift or die $!;
chomp(my @files = <$fn>);

# Variable to contain the current open filehandle
my $curr_fh;
while (<>) {
  # Skip blank lines
  next unless /\S/;

  # If it's the opening of a div...
  if (/\[\[div]]/) {
    # Open the next file...
    open $curr_fh, '>', shift @files or die $!;
    # Print the opening html...
    print $curr_file "<html>\n<body>\n";
    # ... and skip the rest of the loop
    next;
  }

  # If it's the end of a div
  if (/\[\[\/div]]/) {
    # Print the closing html...
    print $curr_fh "</body>\n</html>\n";
    # Close the current file...
    close $curr_fh;
    # Unset the variable so we can reuse it...
    undef $curr_fh;
    # and skip the rest of the loop
    next;
  }

  # Otherwise, just print the record to the currently open file
  print $curr_fh $_;
}
```

Call it with two arguments, the name of the file containing the the filenames (filename.txt) followed by the name of the file containing the data (input.txt).